# _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo undefined when anonymous

Tags: 2013, managed-navigation

I'm trying to use _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo to get the term ID for a friendly url. However, if we're anonymous this is always undefined. How can I get this term id while anonymous?

Comment: See if this works for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedrorod/archive/2013/01/30/managed-metadata-navigation-not-working-for-anonymous-users-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: @uberz91 Thanks for the link, but the terms already have a url. The actual navigation is working fine, the friendly URL links to the correct page. But _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo is undefined

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to an anonymous access site to test, but in my Office 365 environment I can see the navigation term buried in the action attribute of the form, along with a few other goodies:

[image]

Assuming this is present in your environment as well, a little string manipulation or regex wizardry ought to get you what you need.

Comment: Nope, doesn't exist. The form's action is just the url.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variable called _spOriginalFormAction  where you can find the term name and id.

Edit: It seems that this variable is not yet set when display templates are rendered. Here is the function that I ended up using:

```
function setFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo() {
    if (typeof (_spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo) == "undefined" || _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo == null) {
        var formaction = null;
        if (_spOriginalFormAction != "undefined" && _spOriginalFormAction != null) {
            formaction = _spOriginalFormAction;
        } else {
            formaction = document.forms.length > 0 ? document.forms[0].action : null;
        }
        if (formaction) {
            var termName = null;
            var termNameMatches = (/\/([^\/]+)\?/ig).exec(formaction);
            if (termNameMatches && termNameMatches.length > 1) {
                termName = termNameMatches[1];
            }
            var termId = null;
            var termIdMatches = (/TermId=([^\&]+)(?:\&|$)/ig).exec(formaction);
            if (termIdMatches && termIdMatches.length > 1) {
                termId = termIdMatches[1];
            }
            if (termName && termId) {
                _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo = {
                    title: termName,
                    termId: termId
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```